# Stop Angular from listing all from database?

Tags: database, angularjs

I have a simple Angular Script which works like ajax to return search results, but when I don't type anything into the search box, it lists all of the data in the data base, how do I stop this?

My script is here: http://www.elliottcoe.com/search/search.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a built in filter `limitTo: <Any Limitation Number>`

[limitTo docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo)

Comment: I have done this and it does limit it, but just seems a bit random as the names aren't in order.

Comment: I would like it so when the text box is empty, it doesn't display anything.

Comment: Okay so make use of `ng-model` directive and on each keyup check if the the input's value is an empty string if so just change the DOM or set the value of $scope.whatEver data to an empty array.

Answer (score 1):

instead of just validating with null check for empty string

```
if($scope.keywords==null || $scope.keywords.trim()==""){
            $scope.trustedExample = $sce.trustAsHtml("<p>Please enter some text in search field</p>");
        }
```